# Pegar registro com especificações SQL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Olá, boa tarde.
Estou tendo que desenvolver um sisteminha em Java com MySql. É simples, apenas a parte do backend, mas eu sou inciante e não tinha executado querys com java antes hehe.

O sistema é o seguindte, o básico: Tenho um banco de dados com uma tabela chamada 'new_table', que possui um campo 'id_cutomer' e 'vl_total'. Preciso calcular a média dos registros com 'vl_total' maiores que 560 e 'id_cutomer' entre 1500 e 2700 , e listar os valores em ordem descrescente.

Eu fiz o sistema e está funcionando, mas queria saber se não teria como fazer mais pelo SQL do que pelo código em si, pois estou pegando os id, valores e ordenando pelo SQL mas a média desses valores estou fazendo pelo código.

Segue o código do método que calcula media e ordena:

```
public List<Cliente> calculaMedia() throws Exception{
    String sql = "SELECT id_cutomer,vl_total FROM new_table WHERE (vl_total > 560) AND (id_cutomer > 1500  AND id_cutomer < 2700 ) ORDER BY vl_total DESC";


    List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;

    try {
        conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnectionToMySQL();

        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        rset = pstm.executeQuery();

        //Enquanto existir dados no banco de dados, faça
        while(rset.next()){

            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

            cliente.setId(rset.getInt("id_cutomer"));

            cliente.setValorTotal(rset.getDouble("vl_total"));

            clientes.add(cliente);
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Nao pegou ultimo id!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
            if(rset != null){
                rset.close();
            }

            if(pstm != null){
                pstm.close();
            }

            if(conn != null){
                conn.close();
            }

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    }
    return clientes;
}
```

E aqui está a classe que eu crio para testar e fazer o calculo da media:

```
public List<Cliente> calculaMedia() throws Exception{
    String sql = "SELECT id_cutomer,vl_total FROM new_table WHERE (vl_total > 560) AND (id_cutomer > 1500  AND id_cutomer < 2700 ) ORDER BY vl_total DESC";


    List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;

    try {
        conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnectionToMySQL();

        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        rset = pstm.executeQuery();

        //Enquanto existir dados no banco de dados, faça
        while(rset.next()){

            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

            cliente.setId(rset.getInt("id_cutomer"));

            cliente.setValorTotal(rset.getDouble("vl_total"));

            clientes.add(cliente);
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Nao pegou ultimo id!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
            if(rset != null){
                rset.close();
            }

            if(pstm != null){
                pstm.close();
            }

            if(conn != null){
                conn.close();
            }

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    }
    return clientes;
}
```

OBS: A tabela possui registros suficientes para as operações, e está rodando ok.
Agradeço desde já, obrigado.
Abraço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso queira, você pode conseguir esses valores apenas com `querys`. Para conseguir a média diretamente do banco de dados utilize a função `AVG`. Aplicando na sua `query`:

```
SELECT AVG(nt.vl_total) AS media
  FROM new_table nt
 WHERE nt.vl_total > 560
   AND nt.id_cutomer > 1500
   AND nt.id_cutomer < 2700
```

Aplicando a `query` acima no método para calcular a média:

```
public Double avg() throws Exception {
  String query = "SELECT AVG(nt.vl_total) AS media" +
               "\n  FROM new_table nt" +
               "\n WHERE nt.vl_total > 560" +
               "\n   AND nt.id_cutomer > 1500" +
               "\n   AND nt.id_cutomer < 2700";
  Double resultado;

  // AQUI VAI A CONEXÃO COM O BANCO E EXECUÇÃO DA QUERY
  // ...

  rset.next();
  resultado = rset.getDouble("media");

  // FECHAR A CONEXÃO E DEMAIS OPERAÇÕES
  // ...

  return resultado;
}
```

Para conseguir os valores ordenados você pode continuar utilizando a `query` exemplificada na pergunta:

```
SELECT nt.id_cutomer,
       nt.vl_total
  FROM new_table nt
 WHERE nt.vl_total > 560
   AND nt.id_cutomer > 1500
   AND nt.id_cutomer < 2700
 ORDER BY nt.vl_total DESC
```

---

> [**`AVG`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)
>
> Returns the average value of **expr**.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a média dos valores da **expressão**.